# Find the general solution $x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = \frac{1}{x^2}
$$

I divided both sides by x to make the coefficient of dy/dx 1

I found the integrating factor as $$f(x)=-x$$
so now multiplying both sides with the integrating factor f(x),
$$-x\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{-xy}{x}=\frac{-x}{x^3}$$
and i am stuck at this step

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Isn't it $$μ\left(x\right)=e^{\int_{}^{}P(x) dx}$$
where
$$P(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$$
then
$$μ\left(x\right)=e^{\int_{}^{}-\frac{1}{x} dx}$$
which will give 
$$μ\left(x\right)=-x$$?

Comment: $e^{\int \frac{-1}{x}dx} = e^{\ln(\frac{1}{x})} = \frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the entire equation by $x^{2}$.

Then you get :-

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{x^{4}}$$.

So $$\frac{d(\frac{y}{x})}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^{4}}$$.

So $$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{-1}{3x^{3}}+C$$.

Or $$y=\frac{-1}{3x^{2}}+Cx$$